# Функции php, получение данных из mysql

Tags: php

Есть необходимость сделать функцию для получения данных из базы перед основным запросом, чтобы потом подставлять значения из другой таблицы.

Изобретал велосипед, что-то вроде того

```
  function useraccess()
  {
      mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
      mysql_select_db($base);
      q = mysql_query("SELECT `accesslevel` FROM accounts WHERE login = " . $res['commentautor'] . "");
      res = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
      $accesslevel = res['accesslevel'];
  }
```

Вызывать пробовал тоже по разному....

Облазил полгугла, запросы по "функции php" показывают результаты по простым функциям, примеров работы с базой я так и не нашел. (

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста что именно вы хотите от этого кода и что именно у вас не получается т.к. лично я вообще не понял...

Comment: хочу из базы в нужных местах дергать значение accesslevel. если логин при выводе равен уже выведенному имени автора

Comment: Будьте так добры обьясните пожалуйста в чем лежит значение <b>commentautor</b>? Или вы не знаете как сделать чтобы функция чтото возвращала?О_О

Comment: commentautor получается из запроса в базу который выполняется перед этим. да, я никак не могу понять, как сделать, чтобы функция возвращала нужное мне значение, потому что с функциями я никак не могу разобраться.

Comment: можно закрывать)

Comment: Не можно а нужно ато тут куча ТРУ разрабов решили показать как искусно они умеют подключатся и выбирать БД...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообщем сделал вывод, что вы не знаете о return, это ужасно... Возрадуйтесь :)

Например:

```
function getAll() {
   $res = mysql_query('SELECT ........');
   $RETURN = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
   return $RETURN;
}
```

Пример использования:

```
 $all = getAll();
 // теперь в $all у нас лежит $RETURN функции getAll...
```

Конкретно для вашего случая:

```
 // данные функции достаточно вызвать единожды ....
 mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
 mysql_select_db($base);

function getAccess($user) {
     $q=mysql_query('SELECT "accesslevel" FROM accounts WHERE login=' . $user);
     $res=mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
     $accessLevel=res['accesslevel'];
     return $accessLevel;
}
```

И использование соответственно:

```
$userAccess = getAssecs($res['commentautor']);
//     теперь в $userAсcess у нас будет результат выборки ....
```

PS: ужаснее всего то, что я когда учил php, тоже сталкивался с подобным, посему и нет критики с моей стороны типа **как так**

Comment: ща потестим, я на самом деле в шоке... я в принципе 3 года использую пхп где то.. и нигде не видел более менее приличного описания функций и их работы... даже в книжках "за бешеные деньги" которых у меня дома пару штук лежит... нигде не описывают такие вопросы, или есть бла бла бла вот у нас функция поехали дальше, что и как вам пока всё равно не важно....

Comment: Обновил, если интерестно завтра после обеда добавляйтесь в skype <b>alexwindhope</b> там я смогу вам больше рассказать ;)

Comment: ерунда какая то... возвращает Array если идёт SELECT `accessLevel` FROM account WHERE `login` = 'demorian' то есть потом echo $all; выводит на экран Array быть не может. в базе один такой логин.

Comment: Такого быть не может т.к. обрабатывается только 1 ряд выборки, даже если бы таких логинов было бы несколько всеравно такого быть недолжно

Comment: у всех есть свои минусы, я пишу от случая к случаю.. сейчас надо написать сайтик самому а не на джумле за пару минут что нить навоять.
то, что вы переписали только что сам и сделал, дописал $return['acesslevel'], спасибо за помощь) и полностью всё разжевывать никогда нельзя, люди должны сами думать еще, а не готовенькое юзать)

Comment: Да мне нежалко, да и какбы на одной проверке уровня доступа сайт не подымешь :)<br>

Comment: это вообще новости))) просто шаблон дле, там строчка есть, группа юзера.. "реализую" через 5-ю точку))

Answer (score -1):

```
function db_query($query){

        if(!$link = mysql_connect("db_host", "db_user", "db_pass")){
            echo "<br>Не могу соединиться с сервером базы данных<br>";
            exit();
        }
        if(!mysql_select_db($db_name, $link)){
            echo "<br>Не могу выбрать базу данных<br>";
            exit();
        }
        mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');
        $set_query = mysql_query($query);
        if($set_query){
            return $set_query;
        } else {
            return false;
        }   
    }
```

А вот так получение из БД рабоатет:

```
$data = db_query("SELECT * FROM `table_name`");
```

Comment: Вы бы хоть вопрос прочитали чтоле -.-

Comment: `$link` всегда будет false + E_WARNING

Comment: Не понял ?? :)) С какого перепугу он будет фолзом ?:)))) Вот это любопытно :) Поясните, пожалуйста, о, Великий ! :)

Comment: вообще запись !$link = mysql_connect("db_host", "db_user", "db_pass") это страшно -.-

Answer (score -2):

```
  function useraccess($host, $user, $pass, $base)
  {
      mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
      mysql_select_db($base);
      q = mysql_query("SELECT `accesslevel` FROM `accounts` WHERE login = '" . $res['commentautor'] . "'");
      res = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
      $accesslevel = res['accesslevel'];
      return $accesslevel;
  }
```

Нужно теперь, когда используете функцию, постоянно включать хост, юзєр, пасс и тп., потому что у функции такое не засовывается, это нужно отдельно делать. И не забываем про видимость функции, все, что лежит у функции, только в ней и видно, поэтому и нужно, чтоб функция что-то возвращала - то, что будет видно вне функции.

---

Я написал рабочий вариант твоего кода, ведь так не пишется вообще (я про подключение к базе прямо в функции и вместе с селектом). И кстати, я ж написал, что нужно выкинуть чтоб правильно и грамотно было.

```
function useraccess($login)
  {
      $sql = mysql_query("SELECT `accesslevel` FROM `accounts` WHERE login = '{$login}'");
      $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
      $accesslevel = res['accesslevel'];
      return $accesslevel;
  }
```

Минимальные поправки и эта хрень делает то же, что и выше написано. И какие еще дополнительные данные?

Comment: ну если уже принят ответ, нафига писать, тем более, нафига я буду дергать дополнительные данные, если мне нужен только уровень доступа?? это функция для новостей, чтобы у комментатора был usergroupicon ))) и ничего более)) не читаем, потом оказываем "медвежьи услуги" ну зачем так делать.. не пойму.. -